# Follow-up: Drawing Game Tree with Curved Informational Sets and Several Nodes, using Tikz and Forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest, draw, game-tree

This is a follow-up from [Drawing game tree - Tikz or Forest?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497109/drawing-game-tree-tikz-or-forest)

The sequential game tree I am trying to draw is this one: 
[image]

I am using tikz and forest to draw it, but I am still far from it. In particular: I would like to 1. include the names of different players (simply "Player 1" and "Player 2") in different nodes; 2. Create the second nodes for player 1 (with the information set) (in which the strategy is "Introduce Proposal"); 3. Draw the two last information sets (highlighted in blue and red) correctly).

I am sending the code I have so far below:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.misc,arrows.meta,positioning}
\tikzset{rconnect/.style args={#1 and #2}{insert path={
($(#1)+    (270+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/r    adius})$) 
arc(270+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:90+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rcon    nect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius})
to[out=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle},in=180-    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}] 
($(#2)+(90-    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius    })$) 
arc(90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:-90-    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius    })
to[in=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle},out=180-    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}] 
cycle}},rconnect/.cd,radius/.initial=6.5pt,angle/.initial=-12}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=0.1cm,l sep=1.2cm,font=\scriptsize,
where n children=0{align=center,draw,edge={thick,-{Circle}}}                {circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2mm},
where n=1{edge label={node[midway,above left=0pt,font=\scriptsize]{S}}}        {edge
label={node[midway,above right=0pt,font=\scriptsize]{E}}},
edge={thick}
}
  [,label=above:Nature,alias=T
   [,alias=L
   [,alias=LL
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $0$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
    [,alias=LR
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $0$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
   ]
   [,alias=R
    [,alias=RL
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $\bar{R}$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
    [,alias=RR
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $\bar{R}$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
\node[draw,dashed,rounded rectangle,fit=(L) (R)] (F1){};  
\node[draw,dashed,rounded rectangle,fit=(LR) (RL)]{};  
\draw[dashed] let \p1=($(F1.north)-(F1.center)$) in
 [/tikz/rconnect/radius=\y1] [rconnect=LL and RR];
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution to use the [istgame](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{istgame}

\NewDocumentCommand\mact{m}
{\makecell[c]{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\mpay{m}
{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[font=\footnotesize]
\setistmathTF*001
\xtShowEndPoints
% top part
\xtdistance{25mm}{120mm}
\istroot(0)[chance node]{Nature}
  \istb{\mact{$R=O$\\(Cooperative\\Player)}}[above left,xshift=-10pt]
  \istb{\mact{$R=\bar R$\\(Competitive\\Player)}}[above right,xshift=10pt]  \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{50mm}
\istroot(A)(0-1)%<180>{Player 1}
  \istb{\mact{Introduce\\Proposal}}[l]  \endist
\istroot(B)(0-2)%<0>{Player 1}
  \istb{\mact{Introduce\\Proposal}}[r]  \endist
% left part
\xtdistance{25mm}{60mm}
\istroot(A0)(A-1)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{Go}[al]  \istb{Stay}[ar]  \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{30mm}
\istroot(A1)(A0-1)<0>{$(B-C,O)$}
  \istb{\mact{Introduce\\Proposal\\(I)}}[al]  \istb{\mact{Delay\\(D)}}[ar]  \endist
\istroot(A2)(A0-2)<180>{$(B,X)$}
  \istb{I}[al]  \istb{D}[ar]  \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{15mm}
\istroot(A3)(A1-1)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{Go (G)}[l]{\mpay{B-C\\O}}  \istb{Stay (S)}[r]{\mpay{B\\X}}  \endist
\istroot(A4)(A1-2)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{G}[l]{\mpay{B-L\\X-L}}     \istb{S}[r]{\mpay{B-C\\O}}       \endist
\istroot(A5)(A2-1)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{G}[l]{\mpay{B\\X}}         \istb{S}[r]{\mpay{B-L\\X-L}}     \endist
\istroot(A6)(A2-2)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{G}[l]{\mpay{B\\O}}         \istb{S}[r]{\mpay{L\\O}}         \endist
% right part
\xtdistance{25mm}{60mm}
\istroot(B0)(B-1)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{Go}[al]  \istb{Stay}[ar]  \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{30mm}
\istroot(B1)(B0-1)<0>{$(B-C,\bar R)$}
  \istb{I}[al]  \istb{D}[ar]  \endist
\istroot(B2)(B0-2)<180>{$(B,X)$}
  \istb{I}[al]  \istb{D}[ar]  \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{15mm}
\istroot(B3)(B1-1)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{G}[l]{\mpay{B\\-L}}        \istb{S}[r]{\mpay{B-L\\R-L}}  \endist
\istroot(B4)(B1-2)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{G}[l]{\mpay{B\\\bar R}}    \istb{S}[r]{\mpay{B\\O}}      \endist
\istroot(B5)(B2-1)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{G}[l]{\mpay{B\\\bar R}}    \istb{S}[r]{\mpay{B-L\\L}}    \endist
\istroot(B6)(B2-2)<180>{Player 2}
  \istb{G}[l]{\mpay{B-R\\\bar R}}  \istb{S}[r]{\mpay{B-L\\X-L}}  \endist
% information sets
\setxtinfosetstyle{dashed}
\xtInfosetO(A)(B){Player 1}(1.5em)
\xtCInfosetO[blue](A1)!.35!(B1)<1.15>{Player 1}(1.5em)
\xtCInfosetO[red](A2)!.5!(B2)<.75>{Player 1}(1.5em)
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know that `istgame` allows you to draw these shapes. +1

Comment: Also, in the last branches is it possible to remove the nodes? I mean: in the bottom of the figure, the branch that goes to the payoff \mpay{B-C\\O} has a node on it (the black dot in the end of the branch), is it possible to remove the node?

Comment: @Thiago Yes. Just comment out `\xtShowEndPoints`.

Comment: @marmot If you mean the shapes of bubble type curved information sets, yes, they are available with the `istgame` version 2.

Answer (score 5):

The main motivation for posting this is to eliminate the spaces you added in the `rconnect` style, and which cause errors in the above code. Apart from that, you can use labels to add the players. The other request I do not understand because I am not working on game theory, so I do not know what these terms mean.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.misc,arrows.meta,positioning}
\tikzset{rconnect/.style args={#1 and #2}{insert path={
($(#1)+(270+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius})$)
arc(270+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:90+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius})
to[out=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle},in=180-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}]
($(#2)+(90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius})$)
arc(90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:-90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius})
to[in=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle},out=180-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}]
cycle}},rconnect/.cd,radius/.initial=6.5pt,angle/.initial=-12}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=0.1cm,l sep=1.2cm,font=\scriptsize,
where n children=0{align=center,draw,edge={thick,-{Circle}}}                {circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2mm},
where n=1{edge label={node[midway,above left=0pt,font=\scriptsize]{S}}}        {edge
label={node[midway,above right=0pt,font=\scriptsize]{E}}},
edge={thick}
}
  [,label=above:Nature,alias=T
   [,label=above left:Player 1,alias=L
   [,label=above left:Player 2,alias=LL
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $0$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
    [,label=above right:Player 2,alias=LR
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $0$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
   ]
   [,label=above right:Player 1,alias=R
    [,label=above left:Player 2,alias=RL
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $\bar{R}$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
    [,label=above right:Player 2,alias=RR
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $\bar{R}$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
\node[draw,dashed,rounded rectangle,fit=(L) (R)] (F1){};  
\draw[dashed,blue] let \p1=($(F1.north)-(F1.center)$) in
 [/tikz/rconnect/radius=\y1]  [rconnect=LL and RL];
\draw[dashed,red] let \p1=($(F1.north)-(F1.center)$) in
 [/tikz/rconnect/radius=\y1]  [rconnect=LR and RR];
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comment: uisng [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251388/121799) one could do the following: store the items on the left or right in lists, and then attach the items according to the levels. (If you *really* need to, you can replace "Hibernate" by something else.;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.misc,arrows.meta,positioning}
\tikzset{rconnect/.style args={#1 and #2}{insert path={
($(#1)+(270+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius})$)
arc(270+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:90+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius})
to[out=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle},in=180-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}]
($(#2)+(90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius})$)
arc(90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:-90-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/radius})
to[in=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle},out=180-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rconnect/angle}]
cycle}},rconnect/.cd,radius/.initial=6.5pt,angle/.initial=-12}

\begin{document}
\edef\LstLeft{0,"$p$","Go","Wait","A"}
\edef\LstRight{0,"$1-p$","Stay","Hibernate","B"}
\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=0.1cm,l sep=1.2cm,font=\scriptsize,
where n children=0{align=center,draw,edge={thick,-{Circle}}}{circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2mm},
before drawing tree={
        if level=0{}{
          if n'=1{
            edge label/.wrap pgfmath arg={node [midway, right=.5em]
            {\pgfmathparse{{\LstLeft}[#1]}\pgfmathresult}}{level()},
          }{
            edge label/.wrap pgfmath arg={node [midway, left=.5em] 
            {\pgfmathparse{{\LstRight}[#1]}\pgfmathresult}}{level()},
          },
        }{}
      },
%where n=1{edge label={node[midway,above left=0pt,font=\scriptsize]{S}}}{edge label={node[midway,above right=0pt,font=\scriptsize]{E}}},
edge={thick}
}
  [,label=above:Nature,alias=T
   [,label=above left:Player 1,alias=L
   [,label=above left:Player 2,alias=LL
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $0$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
    [,label=above right:Player 2,alias=LR
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $0$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
   ]
   [,label=above right:Player 1,alias=R
    [,label=above left:Player 2,alias=RL
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $\bar{R}$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
    [,label=above right:Player 2,alias=RR
     [
      [{$B-C$ \\ $\bar{R}$}]
      [{$B$ \\ $X$}]
     ]
     [
      [{$B-L$ \\ $R-L$}]
      [{$B-L$ \\ $X-L$}]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
\node[draw,dashed,rounded rectangle,fit=(L) (R)] (F1){};  
\draw[dashed,blue] let \p1=($(F1.north)-(F1.center)$) in
 [/tikz/rconnect/radius=\y1]  [rconnect=LL and RL];
\draw[dashed,red] let \p1=($(F1.north)-(F1.center)$) in
 [/tikz/rconnect/radius=\y1]  [rconnect=LR and RR];
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, Marmot. The two other things are 1. Instead of S and E (these are the strategies) in every branch, I would like to have different strategies. For example in the first two branches, instead of S and E, I would like p and 1-p for example. Then when player 2 is playing I would like to have Go or Stay (instead of S and E again). 2. The second thing is: If you see in the handmaid tree in the question, the order is Nature then Player 1, but Player 1 does not open in two branches (S and E) , player 1 will only have a straight line to player 2 with "Introduce Proposal").

Comment: @Thiago I added something along those lines.